# Change color of date

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

How do I change datepicker backgroundcolor for SU MO TU .....?

Totally noob here... where do i need to look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ui.datepicker.css or in your css file,

check for this

```
.ui-datepicker th { //css code }
```

add background-color to the existing css code.

```
.ui-datepicker th { background-color:#FF0000;//css code }
```